# How to optimize my code for drawing on canvas

Tags: android, canvas

In my android app I am drawing lots of Rectangles, Lines & Arcs
which frequently change on user action.

Now what I have done is created my Paint objects inside the onDraw() method
so that they remain local variables and do not cause any memory issues.

But during a code review this was pointed out as a mistake.
I am told that this might slow down the drawing on canvas as new() will be called each time
onDraw() is called. So I am asked to make Paint objects as class variables, initialize them only once and only change their property in onDraw() and further nullify them when the screen is closed/destroyed.

I want to ask that would this be the right thing to do or things are better the way they already are because I did not find the UI slow on my screen and I doubt that this might be an unnecessary change.

Please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that there is a lag for `Paint paint = new Paint();` during `onDraw()` processing. I now make `paint` a class variable, and in `onDraw()` simply modify the attributes of the already-constructed Paint variable.

```
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        ...
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
        ...
    }
```

Comment: well, anytime you do a `new` there is some time to construct the variable. if the variable is a member variable and has been constructed once (say, in `onCreate()`) then that time already spent. to simply change an attribute of `mPaint` there aren't many cpu cycles spent (i don't have a hard-and-fast number, but i think this is semi-obvious...i hope!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should use Paint as a class member.  The size of Paint is probably small, not that I've checked mind, but it is merely a settings container.

Allocating any objects in Draw is a bad idea as it can cause the GC to kick in and cause a very noticeable glitch, especially on older devices.